# How can I check the word count of selected text in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, word-count

**Is it possible to view the word count for a selected text in Notepad++?**

I'm been able to view the current number of selected characters and lines in the bottom status bar.

[image: Status Bar word count]

I'm able to view the total number of words in my document by opening **View → Summary**.

[image: Word Summary]

Unfortunately, neither option lets me view the word count for my currently selected text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved with the TextFX plugin for Notepad++.

1. Install the plugin by clicking **Plugins** -> **Plugin Manager** -> **Show Plugin Manager**
2. Check **TextFX Characters** in the list of available plugins and click **Install** (Notepad++ will need to restart to finish the installation)
3. After installation finishes, you can view the word count for the selected text by going to the **TextFX** menu, selecting **TextFX Tools** and finally **Word Count**:

[image: TextFX Screenshot]

Comment: You don't need TextFX for this :)

Comment: It seems that TextFX is not there anymore.

Comment: I know it's 2024 now, but I want to clarify that TextFX Characters is now part of the NppTextFX2 plugin and it is there in the list of plugins of the Plugin Manager.

Answer (score 18):

In Notepad++ you can get the words count in two ways

1. In menu, View => summary
2. In status bar, `Double click` on the `length: <some_number>, line : <some_number>` then you can see words count in a pop up windows

[image]

Comment: This shows the word count of the whole document. He asked for the word count of the selected text

Comment: @MoProg : kindly see the last line of the dialog. it shows how many chars are selected

Comment: But as you say, it is the number of chars, not the number of words. He is asking for the number of words in the selected text.

Answer (score 11):

#### Is it possible to view the word count for a selected text?

- Menu "Search" > "Mark".
- Set "Find what" to `\<\w+\>`.
- Enable "In selection".
- Click "Mark All".
- The bottom of the dialog will update with "Mark: *n* matches.
- Click "Clear all marks" to remove the marks.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Even better, there is a specific `count` button now

Comment: 1. Search mode: *Regular expression*, 2. `\<` and `\>` are not required

Comment: @MarianD {shrug} my answer works. If you have a better answer please write your own answer.

Comment: @David, I didn't want to offend you, you answer is nice, I upvoted it before I wrote my comment. IMHO the setting of *Search mode* is important enough to be explicitly stated in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The TextFX plugin mentioned in the accepted answer is still [not available](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17436/textfx-plugin-completely-missing) in the 64bit version of Notepad++, which in 2021 is the version everybody will be using.

There is a trivial solution to counting all the words in a selected region, which *does not* involve plugins and *does not* require one to remember [regex syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

1. One can select the desired text
2. Copy it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Create a new tab with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
4. Paste the selected text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
5. Count all the words on that tab with the `View/Summary...` menu
6. Or double click on the `length:... line:...` field on the status bar

This requires three extra keystrokes but is pretty quick and simple

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't underestimate how many people are using the 32 bit version. I'm still using the 32 bit version for add on compatibility. This is a good workaround for 64 bit users though.

Answer (score 1):

## 2022 update - TextFX is not available for npp 64-bit.

## Alternate solution using RegEx search

1. Select the text.
2. Press `Ctrl+F` to open search window.
3. Enter `\w+` in the search bar.
4. Select "In selection".
5. Select "Regular Expression" in Search mode.
6. Press "Count" to view word count at the bottom of the search window.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the TextFX plugin? You can download it from SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/

Answer (score -1):

Do a simple Find and Replace with the *exact same phrase*. The Find dialog box will tell how many replacements there would be.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. Can you explain a little more clearly? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1):

If you click on a word in your document, then bring up the Find dialogue, there is a button right there on that dialogue labeled Count.

Comment: OP asks for counting **all** the words within a selection, not a secific word.You are counting the number  occurrences of one word.

Answer (score -1):

Fastest solution (2 seconds) is:

1. mark the word or expression you want to count it occurence in your
   document by double klick
   2.go to menue search -> incremental search
   you will see right next to the search box the amount of matches
   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4bom.png)

Alternative:

1. mark the word
2. Ctrl + Alt +I

Comment: OP asks for counting all the words within a selection, not a secific word.You are counting the number of occurrences of a single word.